# How to specify default path for saveAs dialog box for export excel from .net

Tags: .net, excel, export, closedxml

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format(@"attachment;filename={0}.xlsx", sheetName.Replace(" ", "_")));

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    wb.SaveAs(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
    memoryStream.Close();
}

HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I want SaveAs Dialog box to show a default specified path e.g. c:\users\joe\ or save the file in specified directory ?  How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `DefaultFilePath` for your Application object.

```
wb.Application.DefaultFilePath = @"c:\users\joe";
```

Source: [How to: Get and Set the Default File Path for Workbooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tf9k1sdd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)